# Jquery $.ajax not working in mozilla and IE, working well in chrome

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery ajax to send data to to the server. It is working well in chrome but not in my IE and firefox.

```
function login()
{

    var username=$('#username').val();
    var password=$('#password').val();

    if(username=="" || password=="" )
    {
        alert("Please fill all the required fields");
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "../users/login",
            async: false,
            data: 'username='+ username  + '&password='+ password,
            success : function(data) {
               //alert(data);
               if(data=="1")
               {
                   //alert("Successfull");
                   window.location = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'uhome')); ?>";
               }
               else
               {
                   alert("Invalid login credentials. Please check again.");
               }
           }
       });
   }
}
```

Every alert before `$.ajax` is working. But not anything with `ajax` in `Firefox and IE`. Working well in `chrome`. Please advice me a solution.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: advice me a solution Paol Draper..please..I am confused.

Comment: Why `async: false`? Generally speaking, it's not advisable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the way data is passed it's handled differently in different browsers (Please correct me if it isn't the case). You better correct that part as following

```
var postData = {};
postData.username = username;
postData.password = password;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "../users/login",
    async: false,
    data: postData,
    success : function(data) { // You callback function}
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but using the same syntax on IE and Firefox, I get the AJAX call to work. Can you tell specifically what are you getting in network tab of debug console?

Comment: @ Bikas, It is showing Status Code:  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error...Hope you will help me from your experience....

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is server side issue. In your case it's possible that the value server receives is not correct. Just implement the check on server side to handle invalid values and see if this error goes away. We can work on the other part later on.

Comment: ok, butt I didn't get you exactly. How to implement this check on server side. Can you help me out with the coding(if you mean that)

Comment: Check if the parameters you're getting is null. Something like `isset(_remote parameter_)`. If the set value fails, do the needful

Answer (score 1):

data should be a javascript object, like this:

```
data: {'username': username, 'password': password}
```